# Error handling is not working in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

My configuration is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="tReadingMobile"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="ouid"
                   expression="//WorkOUId//text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Time"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="entrymode"
                   expression="//entrymode/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="deviceid"
                   expression="//DeviceId/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="partybranchid"
                   expression="//PartyBranchId/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="userid"
                   expression="//userid/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ReadingDateTime"
                   expression="//ReadingDateTime/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="remarks"
                   expression="//Remarks/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="taskid"
                   expression="//TaskId/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="activityid"
                   expression="//activityid/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="assetid"
                   expression="//AssetId/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="parametersetid"
                   expression="//ParametersetId/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Reading"
                   expression="//ReadingsLiteTaildto"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto"/>
            <target type="property" property="Reading"/>
         </enrich>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Reading" expression="get-property('Reading')"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <p:insert_taction_operation xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <xs:ouid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:ouid>
                  <xs:biztransactiontypeid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:biztransactiontypeid>
                  <xs:transactionnumber xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:transactionnumber>
                  <xs:transactiondate xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:transactiondate>
                  <xs:referencenumber xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:referencenumber>
                  <xs:referencedate xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$3</xs:referencedate>
                  <xs:entrymode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$4</xs:entrymode>
                  <xs:deviceid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$5</xs:deviceid>
                  <xs:partybranchid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$6</xs:partybranchid>
                  <xs:personid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$7</xs:personid>
                  <xs:periodfrom xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$8</xs:periodfrom>
                  <xs:periodto xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$9</xs:periodto>
                  <xs:remarks xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$10</xs:remarks>
                  <xs:tags xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">0</xs:tags>
                  <xs:status xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:status>
                  <xs:version xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">0</xs:version>
                  <xs:createdbyid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$11</xs:createdbyid>
                  <xs:createdon xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$12</xs:createdon>
                  <xs:modifiedbyid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$13</xs:modifiedbyid>
                  <xs:modifiedon xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$14</xs:modifiedon>
               </p:insert_taction_operation>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="get-property('ouid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('Time')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('Time')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('entrymode')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('deviceid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('partybranchid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('userid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('ReadingDateTime')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('ReadingDateTime')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('remarks')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('userid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('ReadingDateTime')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('userid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('ReadingDateTime')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="tActionid_Seq">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/taction_DataService/"
                        format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="fault">
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

And my sequence file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="tActionid_Seq" onError="fault">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
             name="ActionID"
             expression="//s:actionid/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           xpath="get-property('taskid')='0' or get-property('taskid')='-1'">
      <then>
         <property name="actiontype" value="1"/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <property name="actiontype" value="0"/>
      </else>
   </filter>
   <log level="custom">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="kk"
                expression="get-property('ActionID')"/>
   </log>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="kk"
             expression="get-property('ActionID')"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <p:insert_tactiondetail_operation xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xs:actionid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:actionid>
            <xs:slno xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:slno>
            <xs:actiontype xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:actiontype>
            <xs:taskid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$3</xs:taskid>
            <xs:partybranchid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$4</xs:partybranchid>
            <xs:activityid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$5</xs:activityid>
            <xs:assetid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$6</xs:assetid>
            <xs:parametersetid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$7</xs:parametersetid>
            <xs:actionstatus xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:actionstatus>
            <xs:reasonid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">-1</xs:reasonid>
            <xs:remarks xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$8</xs:remarks>
            <xs:periodfrom xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$9</xs:periodfrom>
            <xs:periodto xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$10</xs:periodto>
            <xs:duration xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">0</xs:duration>
            <xs:alerts xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:alerts>
         </p:insert_tactiondetail_operation>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('kk')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('actiontype')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('taskid')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('partybranchid')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('activityid')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('assetid')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('parametersetid')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('remarks')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('ReadingDateTime')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('ReadingDateTime')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              expression="get-property('Message')"/>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send receive="tActiondetailid_Seq">
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/tactiondetail_DataService/"
                  format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Here's my WSO2DSS.

```
 <sql>INSERT INTO public.taction(ouid,biztransactiontypeid,transactionnumber,transactiondate,referencenumber,referencedate,entrymode,deviceid,partybranchid,personid,periodfrom,periodto,remarks,tags,status,version,createdbyid,createdon,modifiedbyid,modifiedon) VALUES(?,?,?,(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + ?/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'),?,(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + ?/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'),?,?,?,?,(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + ?/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'),(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + ?/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'),?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + ?/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'),?,(SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + ?/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second'))</sql>
      <result element="GeneratedKeys" rowName="Entry" useColumnNumbers="true">
         <element column="1" name="actionid" xsdType="BIGINT"/>
      </result>
      <param name="ouid" ordinal="1" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="biztransactiontypeid" ordinal="2" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="transactionnumber" ordinal="3" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="transactiondate" ordinal="4" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
      <param name="referencenumber" ordinal="5" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="referencedate" ordinal="6" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
      <param name="entrymode" ordinal="7" sqlType="SMALLINT"/>
      <param name="deviceid" ordinal="8" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="partybranchid" ordinal="9" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="personid" ordinal="10" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="periodfrom" ordinal="11" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
      <param name="periodto" ordinal="12" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
      <param name="remarks" ordinal="13" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="tags" ordinal="14" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="status" ordinal="15" sqlType="SMALLINT"/>
      <param name="version" ordinal="16" sqlType="SMALLINT"/>
      <param name="createdbyid" ordinal="17" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="createdon" ordinal="18" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
      <param name="modifiedbyid" ordinal="19" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="modifiedon" ordinal="20" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
   </query>
   <query id="update_taction_query" useConfig="default">
```

While I am giving proper data, it is working. But an error occurs that's not being handled. I added the default fault sequence but it's not working. Please help me.

Comment: why all CAPS ? sounds so rude .

Answer (score 0):

try like this; add a fault sequence to your proxy

```
 <target faultSequence="fault">
```

Comment: thanx..for answer sorry i am not clear i can add two target in proxy as per your suggestion..let mew know i am confused.my proxy error is   ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,167]

Comment: if error occuered in dss like primarykey voilation in this case fault is not working..we can handle the wso2dss errors in wso2esb using faultsequence ..otherwise we can handle in wso2dss level only pls let me know i am confused

Comment: any body knows about this i am waiting for answer i